# Kafka Connector doesn't display in Confluent Control Center

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am completely new to Kafka Connect, Confluent Platform etc.
I've used [this instruction](https://docs.confluent.io/operator/2.0.0/co-quickstart.html) and installed Confluent Platform and control center.
But when I add connector It doesn't display in control center (see screenshot)

[image]
However when I do curl command like this: `curl http://localhost:8083/connectors/expedia`

I get the response:

```
{"name":"expedia","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.azure.blob.storage.AzureBlobStorageSourceConnector","azblob.container.name":"m11kafkaconnect","transforms.MaskField.replacement":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","format.class":"io.confluent.connect.azure.blob.storage.format.avro.AvroFormat","transforms.MaskField.fields":"date_time","confluent.topic.bootstrap.servers":"kafka:9071","azblob.account.key":"SOMEKEY","transforms.MaskField.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.MaskField$Value","confluent.topic.replication.factor":"3","azblob.account.name":"SOMEBLOBNAME","name":"expedia","transforms":"MaskField"},"tasks":[],"type":"source"}%
```

So does it mean the connector has been created and why it isn't displayed in control center panel?

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: It's created, but there's no tasks, so it's not running. Also, screenshots aren't helpful. Look at the logs for errors reading your connect cluster information